# Find the asymptotic growth of $t(n)$ satisfying $t(n)=2^nt(n/2)+n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

> Find $\Theta$ of $t(n)$ for
>
> $$ t(n)=2^nt(n/2)+n .$$

I can't use **Master Theorem** because of $2^nt$ and althought I am familiar with other methods, I can't solve it. Is there a chance solve it using **Recursive Tree** method? If not, choose whatever method you can handle.

Comment: They don't matter for Landau classes, but what are the anchors?

Comment: There is no more notes or anchors in the task.

Comment: Then $t$ is, technically, not well-defined; easy loop-hole. ;)

Comment: I haven't seen the word "anchor" in this context before, but I presume it means the same as the "base case" (e.g., $t(0)$ or $t(1)$ or some such). Am I correct?

Comment: @Srivatsan I think you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=t(1)$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
t(2^1)&=2^{2^1}a+2^1\;;\\
t(2^2)&=2^{2^2}\left(2^{2^1}a+2^1\right)+2^2\\
&=2^{2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^2+1}+2^2\;;\\
t(2^3)&=2^{2^3}\left(2^{2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^2+1}+2^2\right)+2^3\\
&=2^{2^3+2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^3+2^2+1}+2^{2^3+2}+2^3\;;\\
t(2^4)&=2^{2^4}\left(2^{2^3+2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^3+2^2+1}+2^{2^3+2}+2^3\right)+2^4\\
&=2^{2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^4+2^3+2^2+1}+2^{2^4+2^3+2}+2^{2^4+3}+2^4\;;\\
t(2^5)&=2^{2^5+2^4+2^4+2^3+2^2+2^1}a+2^{2^5+2^4+2^3+2^2+1}+2^{2^5+2^4+2^3+2}+2^{2^5+2^4+3}+2^{2^5+4}+2^5\;;\\
&\vdots\\
t(2^k)&=2^{2^{k+1}-2}a+\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{i+\sum_{j=i+1}^k 2^j}\\
&=2^{2^{k+1}-2}a+\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{i+2^{k+1}-2^{i+1}}\;,
\end{align*}$$

so if $n=2^k$,

$$\begin{align*}
t(n)&=2^{2n-2}a+\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{2n+i-2^{i+1}}\\
&=2^{2n-2}a+2^{2n}\sum_{i=1}^k 2^{i-2^{i+1}}\\
&=2^{2n-2}a+2^{2n}\frac{2^{k+1}-2}{4\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{2^i}}\\
&=2^{2n-2}\left(a+\frac{2n-2}{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{2^i}}\right)\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now $$2^{n/2}=2^{2^{k-1}}\le\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{2^i}<2^{2^k}=2^n\;,$$ so

$$2^{2n-2}\left(a+\frac{2n-2}{2^n}\right)<t(n)\le2^{2n-2}\left(a+\frac{2n-2}{2^{n/2}}\right)\;,$$

or $$2^{2n-2}a+(2n-2)2^{n-2}<t(n)\le 2^{2n-2}a+(2n-2)2^{\frac{3n}2-2}\;.$$ Clearly the $2^{2n-2}a$ term is dominant, so $t(n)$ is $\Theta(2^{2n})$ for $n$ a power of $2$.

Comment: Typically, you will want to add an induction proof because of "...".

Comment: @Raphael: Of course, but I’m leaving that detail for the OP to fill in.

Comment: Ehm, and what is answer on the question? I need $\Theta$ not $\Omega$

Comment: @Andrew: $\Omega$ was a typo for $\Theta$, which I’ve now fixed. (That really should have been pretty clear if you looked at the last inequality.)

Answer (score 1):

Introduce $s(n)=t(n)/4^n$ and $r(n)=n/4^n$, then $s(n)=s(n/2)+r(n)$. Introduce $\sigma(k)=s(2^k)$ and $\varrho(k)=r(2^k)$, then $\sigma(k)=\sigma(k-1)+\varrho(k)$, that is
$$
\sigma(k)=\sigma(0)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\varrho(i).
$$
Since $\varrho(i)=2^i/4^{2^i}=2^{i-2\cdot2^i}$ is summable, $\sigma(0)\leqslant\sigma(k)\leqslant\sigma(0)+\tau$ for every $k$, where $\tau=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}\varrho(i)$ is finite. In particular $t(2^k)/4^{2^k}=s(2^k)=\sigma(k)=\Theta(1)$, that is $t(2^k)=\Theta(4^{2^k})$.